# fetch data from a component and render it in another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Any clue why below code doesn't work? It's just a simple ajax call then trying to render in another component. I don't know where's the error is.

```
       var Names = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
      const self = this;
      const names = fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/ksgah')
        .then(function(response) {
          return response.json()
        })
        .then(function(response) {
          self.setState({'names':response.name})
        })
      return {names: names};
    },
    render() {
      return (
        <Hello name={this.state.names}/>
      )
    }
})

var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return(
      <ul>
      {
        this.props.names.map(name => {
          return <li>{name}</li>
        })
      }
      </ul>
      )
    }
 })

ReactDOM.render( <Names/> , document.getElementById('container'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kzfufntw/

Answer (score 0):

cahnge the quots to {}

```
// from:
 <Hello name="this.state.names"/>
//to:
 <Hello name={this.state.names}/>
```

also the set state is wrong use : instead ,

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you get `Promise` in the `names` constant in the `getInitialState` and you returns state { names: Promise } into your component. So it hasn't `map` method and fails.

So you should return a valid initialState without any async actions, like this: `getInitialState: function() { return { names: [] }; }`.

And then do async call and update state on `componentDidMount`, for example.

Check this out: [fixed jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kzfufntw/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <Hello name={this.state.names}/>
```

You're passing prop `name` while the component expects `names`.

Also, `names` should be an empty array when you start, not a reference to a Promise:

```
getInitialState: function () {
  const self = this;
  fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/ksgah')
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json()
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      self.setState({'names':response.name})
    })
  return {names: []};
},
```